# Python Selenium ChromeDriver Fails to start after 8 threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to create an automation tool that utilises as many browser instances as possible. After creating 8 instances, when I try to get the 9th instance, I get the following errors :

```
Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn''t exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so 
ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)


Message: unknown error: unable to discover open window in chrome
(Session info: headless chrome=103.0.5060.134)

Message: session not created
from tab crashed
(Session info: headless chrome=103.0.5060.134)
```

The reason I get 3 of them is I am trying 2 more times after getting an exception. My browser options are like following:

```
opt.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
opt.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
opt.add_argument("--disable-site-isolation-trials")
opt.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
opt.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
opt.add_argument("--headless")
opt.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
```

I made some research about it but couldn't find any solution. Am I limited to 8 instances at the same time?